# Cocoa AVPlayer with addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, avplayer

I am using `AVPlayer` in my application. I use `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval` to update UI with current play status.

```
CMTime tm = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.1, 100);

[player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:tm     
queue:dispatch_get_main_queue() usingBlock:^(CMTime time) {

        NSDateFormatter *DateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:mmm"];
        NSLog(@"%@",[DateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
}
```

My goal is to refresh every 10th of a second. However, the code block only gets executed every second. Is this the smallest unit it can run or do I do something wrong to make the polling happen every 10th of a second ?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Edit:
Actually, after further investigation it seems that callbacks actually work every 10th of a second however when I ask the player for current time for some wav files it takes a second to get the response while others work correctly. Anyone experienced that ?

Comment: I believe the reason is outside the code we see here. Can you try to reproduce the issue using Apple's [AVSimplePlayer sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVSimplePlayerOSX/Introduction/Intro.html)? I am able to get 10 callbacks per second inside AVSimplePlayer, using both `CMTimeMake(1, 10)` (from Apple's code) and your `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.1, 100)`.

Comment: Actually, after further investigation it seems that callbacks actually work every 10th of a second however when I ask the player for current time for some wav files it takes a second to get the response while others work correctly. Anyone experienced that ?

Answer (score 1):

Update CMTime tm = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.1, 100);

to CMTime tm = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.1, 10);

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend moving the creation of your DateFormatter outside of the block.  You should only need to alloc/init it once and it can be fairly expensive.